# Return success/error response after making some graph calls

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have the following code to add users to AAD group:

```
        public async Task AddUsersToGroup(IEnumerable<BatchRequestContent> batches)
        {            
            try
            {
                foreach (var batchRequestContent in batches)
                {
                    var response = await _graphServiceClient
                        .Batch
                        .Request()
                        .WithMaxRetry(10)
                        .PostAsync(batchRequestContent);

                    var responses = await response.GetResponsesAsync();

                    foreach (string key in responses.Keys)
                    {
                        var httpResponse = await response.GetResponseByIdAsync(key);
                        httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();                       
                    }                    
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await _log.LogMessageAsync(new LogMessage
                {
                    Message = ex.GetBaseException().ToString(),
                    RunId = RunId
                });

                throw;
            }
        }
```

I need to update this method to return 'Ok' if all the requests returned a success response, else return 'Error' if any of the requests returned an error response. How would I do that? Please help!

```
        private IEnumerable<BatchRequestContent> GetBatchRequest(IEnumerable<AzureADUser> users, AzureADGroup targetGroup)
        {
            var batches = new List<BatchRequestContent>();
            int maxNoBatchItems = 20;

            var batchRequestContent = new BatchRequestContent();
            int requestId = 1;

            foreach (var user in users)
            {
                JObject body = new JObject
                {
                    ["members@odata.bind"] = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user.ObjectId}"
                };

                var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Patch, $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{targetGroup.ObjectId}");
                httpRequestMessage.Content = new StringContent(body.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                batchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStep(new BatchRequestStep(requestId.ToString(), httpRequestMessage));

                if (batchRequestContent.BatchRequestSteps.Count() % maxNoBatchItems == 0)
                {
                    batches.Add(batchRequestContent);
                    batchRequestContent = new BatchRequestContent();
                }

                requestId++;
            }

            if (batchRequestContent.BatchRequestSteps.Count < maxNoBatchItems)
            {
                batches.Add(batchRequestContent);
            }

            return batches;
        }
```

Comment: Just see this doc provided by official about how to send batch requests: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/graphapi-batching/blob/master/Program.cs

Comment: Thank you so much. On trying this code, I see a bad request response code 400. Could you please let me know why is that?

Comment: Could you pls share your request content?

Comment: Updated my question with the code to get batches - it includes the request content. Please let me know if you need any other details. Thank you!